# I get an error while compiling on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

When trying to run this code on Xcode, #include vcl.h gets an error that says vcl.h file not found. Can someone help me fix it? The error occurs in the first line of the program code.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdexcept>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have vcl.h in your project?

Comment: If it's Borland's VCL, it wouldn't run on your Mac even if it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

vcl.h is provided by Borland C++ Builder.  It is not a standard library, so you need to provide it somehow.

It appears that the old C++ builder is now the [Embarcadero C++ Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder), so you may need to install that library first

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the angled brackets, have you tried a quoted import?

```
#include "vcl.h"
```

Do you actually have the header and associated file in your project? because I don't think `vcl.h` is a system library. All I can find about it is that it is a Borland specific file, which does not come with Xcode.

Comment: tried the quotes. didn't work.

Comment: I'm not surprised. Looking at the entire code you originally put in your question it looks like you are trying to compile code that is originally meant for Borland's C++ compiler. Xcode doesn't have TList objects.

Comment: Is there any way in which the code can run in Xcode?

Comment: No. Because the Borland Compiler's component library is for Windows.